# Create custom block in custom theme

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, frontend

I'm trying to create a **custom block** in the theme I created for **Magento 2.1.8**.

When I add the  element to the `default.xml` layout, I got the following exception:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: frontend\Custom\Simple\Block\Services
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class frontend\Custom\Simple\Block\Services does not exist
```

In the `Custom/Simple/Block/Services.php` I have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Simple\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
* Services block
*/
class Services extends Template {
    public function getTitle() {
        return "Services";
    }
}
```

In the `default.xml` I've added this code:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="frontend\Custom\Simple\Block\Services" name="services.test" template="Custom_simple::test.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="something" xsi:type="string">Value</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

I've tried to change the class to: `Custom\Simple\Block\Services` and I got the same error.

Thanks for your help!

### Edit:

In the `registration.php` I have the following code:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Customdac/Simple',
__DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that all this code should be located at `app\code\Custom\Simple` because you are creating a module not a theme.

And the other thing is you are giving wrong block & template location in the `default.xml` file give it as below & this file should be located at `app\code\Custom\Simple\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Custom\Simple\Block\Services" name="services.test" template="Custom_Simple::test.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="something" xsi:type="string">Value</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

and for the `registration.php` file there should be this code for the registration of the module & this file should be located at `app\code\Custom\Simple\registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_Simple',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: to insert your custom blocks into your theme you need to create modules it will not work from theme

Comment: Thank you! I came to the same conclusion after a couple of working hours :)

Comment: if my answer was help full to you don't forget to vote & accept it so it could be helpful to others also facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use

> class="Custom\Simple\Block\Services"

Instead of

> class="frontend\Custom\Simple\Block\Services"

Comment: Thanks but it still not working. :( In the registration.php, should I write "frontend\Custom\Simple" or without frontend?

Comment: `without frontend` and it should be located at `app\code\Custom\Simple`

Comment: If I want to add a block to my theme, shouldn't it be located at `app\design\frontend\Custom\Simple`? I have to write a module for it instead?

Comment: Block class  never located at `app\design\frontend\Custom\Simple`,it template files can be located at  `app\design\frontend\{VendorName}\{ThemeName}\templates\Custom_Simple\test.phtml`

Comment: Your have some confusion on magento,Please study magento2

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html checkout this link

Comment: Please study magento2 ,Then oneday, you will be champ!!!!